# Running daemon as regular application

Tags: daemon

There are tools that enable one to run a console command or a console application as a daemon. To "daemonize" it, so to say.

Is there a way to run a daemon as a regular console application?

I'm coding in KDevelop and don't see any options for daemon debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from a misunderstanding of what a daemon is in unix. One of the core ideas in unix is that everything is a file. Following from that is that a program is just a program. It has three file descriptors open when it starts and can open more. From a compiler and debugger there is no difference between filters, curses applications, X applications, utilities and daemons. the only difference between a daemon and any other type of program is that a daemon may close standard io and fork itself so that it no longer has a parent. Most programs that do this have a command line option to disable this behavior. The debugger and development environment have no effect on this.